# Docusign - Couldn't access the class "RecipientPreviewRequest" in SDK package

Tags: python, python-3.x, docusignapi, docusignapextoolkit

I've tried to create a recipient preview for an envelope, for which the class `RecipientPreviewRequest` is required.

I was able to find this in [github](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-python-client/blob/master/docusign_esign/models/recipient_preview_request.py), but I am getting the following error when I try to use it:

> AttributeError: module 'docusign_esign' has no attribute 'RecipientPreviewRequest'

I am using the docusign sdk version  3.3.0 [python-based]
My use case is to preview the signer experience of the envelope.

Is this a known issue? Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: The problem was that the module [RecipientPreviewRequest] was not imported in the init.py. Adding -- from .models.recipient_preview_request import RecipientPreviewRequest -- this line has solved the issue.